# Nginx compression enabled and adviced in Web Page Performance Test

Tags: javascript, nginx, header, compression, gzip

On chrome developer tool I have for this JS file on Network tab:

```
content-type: application/javascript
Request URL: /include/bootstrap/4.5.0/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

The server is a Nginx server for which the compression is enabled (nginx.conf):

```
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 8;
    gzip_min_length 20;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

And yet on several online tool like https://webpagetest.org I get for all my js files:

```
Use gzip compression for transferring compressable responses: 69/100Learn More
705.7 KB total in compressible text, target size = 486.2 KB - potential savings = 219.4 KB

FAILED - (79.2 KB, compressed = 21.2 KB - savings of 58.0 KB) - /include/bootstrap/4.5.0/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
FAILED - (87.4 KB, compressed = 30.2 KB - savings of 57.2 KB) - /include/plugins/js/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js
```

So, is it compressed? If so why it's analysed as not compressed by https://webpagetest.org or https://gtmetrix.com?